# Seeding objects with datetime Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, datetime

I'm trying to seed multiple files to my rails app to test the page structure, and one of the attributes is a datetime stamp. However, I can't figure out how to seed this field. I've tried created_at, but it's not recognized. I couldn't find an example in the ruby docs or railscast, unfortunately.

Any idea how to go about doing this? Thanks

```
12.times { Post.create(title: 'pellentesque', body: 'Lorem ut vehicula', postnumber: '1', date: created_at, image_url: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/19/John_Calvin_-_Young.jpg') }
```

Comment: What is the fields name that has a datetime column type? For example if you want to overwrite the `created_at` field you can just do a `Post.create(title: "foobar", created_at: Time.now - 1.days)`

Comment: Are you getting an error? created_at and updated_at are set automatically by active record and don't need to be set manually. If you want to set this field you could try wrapping it using [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1386556/4358503) . If you're trying to set a custom field you set it like anything else using `code` field_name: Time.current `code` . If this doesn't help I'd suggest posting your schema and an error if you are receiving one.

Comment: @23tux the field name is simply 'date' and I assigned datetime as the field, which works if adding posts via the form, but not via seeding. You're thinking I could delete that column and migrate in a created_at: Time.now column instead? 
Datise I'm just getting a syntax error, goes away once I remove the date attribute, so I think I'm just not getting what syntax to field datetimes with.

Comment: No, don't delete the `created_at` field. What is your exact error when you execute the line in your question?

Comment: NameError: undefined local variable or method `created_at' for main:Object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable passed to date: needs to be a date or time object:

```
some_date = 4.days.ago

12.times do 
  Post.create(
    title: 'pellentesque', 
    body: 'Lorem ut vehicula', 
    postnumber: '1', 
    date: some_date, # some_date passed to date attribute
    image_url: 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/19/John_Calvin_-_Young.jpg'
  ) 
end
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked nicely! Leaving this for reference for future answer-seekers: 
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/DateTime.html 

Show the source for a code for examples.
I used 'date: Time.zone.now.to_datetime' to display the current time.

Answer (score 0):

If the database field is timestamp you wouldn't have to manually set it. It would be set when you create a new row.

If you want to manually set it, you have to create a timestamp like this: `Time.strptime('06/30/2012 00:00', '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M')`.